# Highcharts not displaying telangana state

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I want to show telangana state in map, I am using highmap , but there is no way to show this. IS there any updated svg available with telangana. Can somebody help me to get out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each map from our [store](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/) can be edited and customised by the QGIS tool.

For further clues how to edit, please visit our website with manual:

- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps